# Using qrcode in Python 3.6 to create batches of QR Codes as images

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, qr-code

I'm running Python 3.6 on a Windows 10 machine and would like to create batches of QR codes as PNGs directly from python.  I'll be using the qrcode to create batches of 100 to 200 individual QR codes.  The images will then be used in a mail merge to create individual documents.  I can create individual images using the qr.exe script, but am not able to create the QR code PNGs within Python.

While reading through the documentation for qrcode, I am running into some trouble getting the "Pure Python PNG" working (https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/master/README.rst).

Specifically, when I try to install pymaging using PIP at the command prompt

pip install git+git://github.com/ojii/pymaging.git#egg=pymaging
pip install git+git://github.com/ojii/pymaging-png.git#egg=pymaging-png

I get the following reports

Collecting pymaging from git+git://githumb.com/ojii/pymaging.git#egg=pymaging
Cloning git://github.com/ojii/pymaging.git to c:\Users\B\AppDataq\Local\Temp\pip-build-jioh63js\pymaging

Then I get the following error

Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git clone -q git://github.com/ojii/pymaging.git c:\Users\B\AppDataq\Local\Temp\pip-build-jioh63js\pymaging
Cannot find command 'git'

I've looked at the temp folder and do not see any pip* folders.  Do you have any suggestions on how to get pymaging installed?

-- Update --

Once git is installed the commands can be run from git's bash and pymaging is installed.

Comment: do you have `git` installed?

Comment: Thanks!  I downloaded the most recent version of git and from the git bash I was able to install pymaging.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for creating batches of QR codes as images in Python 3 was a bit slim, specifically the final steps to writing the actual image files ([see qrcode 5.3 documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/qrcode)), so I wanted to share some code I modified and got working.  The original code for Python 2.7 came from [prasopensource's blog](https://prasopensource.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/generating-qrcodes-from-python/).  Below is the script I created for Python 3.6.

```
import qrcode, os.path
print('What is the name of the file containing the data for the QR codes?')
fname = input().strip()
file = open(fname, "r")
print()
for x in file:
    x = x.rstrip()
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(version=1, error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,box_size=10,border=4,)
    qr.add_data(x)
    qr.make(fit=True)
    img = qr.make_image()
    file_name = x + ".png"
    print('Saving %s' % file_name)
    image_file = open(file_name, "w")
    img.save(file_name)
    image_file.close()
file.close()

# INFORMATION ABOUT QRCode SETTINGS
#The version parameter is an integer from 1 to 40 that controls the size of the QR Code (the smallest, version 1, is a 21x21 matrix). Set to None and use the fit parameter when making the code to determine this automatically.

#The error_correction parameter controls the error correction used for the QR Code. The following four constants are made available on the qrcode package:
#ERROR_CORRECT_L
#About 7% or less errors can be corrected.
#ERROR_CORRECT_M (default)
#About 15% or less errors can be corrected.
#ERROR_CORRECT_Q
#About 25% or less errors can be corrected.
#ERROR_CORRECT_H.
#About 30% or less errors can be corrected.

#The box_size parameter controls how many pixels each “box” of the QR code is.

#The border parameter controls how many boxes thick the border should be (the default is 4, which is the minimum according to the specs).
```